# How to: Total that multiplies price by quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a price list using an adapted version of list.js.

Currently I've got checkboxes next to each line of product and each checkbox that is checked adds to the total which is correct.

I have added a quantity input next to each of the checkboxes, but I'd like this quantity to multiply by the price (which currently has no js for). Here's a snippet of the code so far.

**JS**:

```
<script>
 function totalIt() {
 var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
 var total = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
 if (input[i].checked) {
   total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
  }
 }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
 }
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<tr>
 <td class="id" style="display:none;">1</td>
 <td name="unit" class="unit">300mm Base Unit</td>
 <td name="range" class="range">Amalfi</td>
 <td name="style" class="style">Cream Gloss</td>
 <td name="price" class="price">&pound;45.94
 <input name="product" value="45.94" type="checkbox" class="tickbox" id="squaredThree" onclick="totalIt()"/>
 <label for="squaredThree"></label>
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="id" style="display:none;">1</td>
 <td class="unit">400mm Base Unit</td>
 <td class="range">Amalfi</td>
 <td class="style">Cream Gloss</td>
 <td class="price">&pound;47.94
 <input name="product" value="45.94" type="checkbox" class="tickbox"    id="squaredThree2" onclick="totalIt()"/>
 <label for="squaredThree2"></label>
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
</tr>
```

If anyone could spare the time to update the JS to perform such function or could give me any guidance it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to multiply the `product` value by the related `quantity` field:

```
function totalIt() {
    var products = document.getElementsByName("product");
    var quantities = document.getElementsByName("quantity");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].checked) {
            total += parseFloat(products[i].value) * parseInt(quantities[i].value, 10);
        } 
    }
    document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, spot on. Although it does require rechecking the selection each time the quantity changes though I can look into that myself.

Comment: Yep, look in to the `keyup` event for that. I would also suggest you look into using jQuery for sending the AJAX request as well as hooking up events. You can make your code much shorter and simpler.